# Java does not append to the .DAT file

Tags: java, file-io

I am writing a basic program that has 3 menu options: Create User, Sign In, and Exit. The user can then choose one of these menu options.

If they choose Create User, they will be prompted to enter a User ID and password (which must follow patterns), and will then check against a .DAT file to ensure the User ID has not already been taken. After successful completion, the program will write the new User ID and password to the end of the .DAT file.

If they choose Sign In, they will be prompted to enter their User ID, followed by their Password, and the program will then read the .DAT file to validate they are on record.

Choosing exit will display a message, "You have signed out."

I am fairly new at java programming just as a forewarning.

Issues I am encountering with my code: 
Choosing new user does not append to the .DAT file
Choosing Sign In - program does not seem to correctly check .DAT file because even-
though I am entering an existing account information it still gives my error "Invalid User ID."

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * This program will utilize a menu structure and validate input if the user doesn't choose
 * a correct option. Writes a new ID and password to .dat file when user chooses to 
 * create new user from menu.
 * 
 * @author CMS
 * @Date 7/28/2014
 */
public class Passwordv2 {
static boolean answer = true;
static final String MENUANSW = "[1-3]{1}", USERID = "[A-Z,a-z]{6}-[0-9]{2}"; //, PASSWORD = "";
static String iMenuOption="", iID, recPassword, recUserID, password;
static Scanner scanner,scannerDat;
static PrintWriter pw;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    init();
    while (answer == true) {
        menu();
        if (iMenuOption.equals("1")) createUser();
        else 
            if (iMenuOption.equals("2")) signIn();
            else {answer = false;}

        }
    closing();

} // end of main

public static void init(){

//User input scanner
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
//PrintWriter
    try {
        pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream (new File ("account.dat"),true) );
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
    }
} // end of INIT

public static String menu(){

    do {System.out.println("Please select from the following:");
        System.out.println("1. Create a New User");
        System.out.println("2. Sign in");
        System.out.println("3. Exit");
        iMenuOption = scanner.next();
        answer = isValMenuOption(iMenuOption);
        if (answer == false) { System.out.print("Incorrect Choice. ");}
    } while (!answer);
    return iMenuOption;

}

public static boolean isValMenuOption(String iMenuOption) {
    return(iMenuOption.matches(MENUANSW));

}
public static void createUser() {
    boolean validID = true, newID = true;
    do {if (!validID) {System.out.println("User ID did not meet requirements.");}
        if (!newID) {System.out.println("This User ID has been taken.");}
        System.out.println("Please select a User Id (6 letters, followed by a dash (-), followed by 2 numbers).");
        iID = scanner.next();
        validID = isValidID(iID);
        newID = isNewID(iID);}
    while (validID==false || newID == false);

    boolean valLength = true, valNum = true, valUpper = true, valLower = true;
    do{ System.out.println("Please select a Password:");
        System.out.println("(6-12 characters, one number, one upper case, one lower case, no white space or symbols).");
        password = scanner.next();
        valLength = isValLength(password);
        valNum = valNum(password);
        valUpper = valUpper(password);
        valLower = valLower(password);}
    while (!valLength || !valNum || !valUpper || !valLower);
    pw.println(iID);
    pw.println(password);
    //menu();
}

public static boolean isValidID(String iID){
    return(iID.matches(USERID));
}

public static boolean isNewID(String iID){

    answer = true;
    // Dat file scanner
    try {
        scannerDat = new Scanner(new File("account.dat"));
        scannerDat.useDelimiter("\r\n");
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("File error");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    while (scannerDat.hasNext()) {
        recUserID = scannerDat.next();
        recPassword = scannerDat.next();
        if (recUserID.equals(iID)) {
            answer = false;
            break;

        }
    }
    return answer; 
}

public static boolean isValLength(String password) {
    if (password.length()  <6 || password.length() > 12) System.out.println("Password did not meet length requirements. ");
    return(password.length() >= 6 && password.length() <= 12);

}

public static boolean valNum(String password) {
    if (password.matches(".*[0-9].*") == false) System.out.println("Password must contain at least one number. ");
    return(password.matches(".*[0-9].*"));
}

public static boolean valUpper(String password){
    if (password.matches(".*[A-Z].*") == false) System.out.println("Password must contain one upper case letter.");
    return (password.matches(".*[A-Z].*")); 

}

public static boolean valLower(String password){
    if (password.matches(".*[a-z].*") == false) System.out.println("Password must contain one lower case letter.");
    return (password.matches(".*[a-z].*")); 
}

public static void signIn() {
    boolean newID;
    System.out.println("Enter User ID.");
    iID = scanner.next();
    System.out.println("Enter Password.");
    password = scanner.next();
    newID = isNewID(iID);
    if (newID == false) {
        if (password.equals(recPassword)) {System.out.println("Authenticated. You have signed in.");}
        else {System.out.println("Invalid Password.");}
    }
    else {System.out.println("Invalid User ID.");}      
}

public static void closing(){
    System.out.println("You signed out.");
    pw.close();
}
} // end of program
```

My .DAT file simply has

aabbcc-11
Onetwo3
aaabbb-22
Onetwo34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all who replied. In the end, the problem ended up being that I had a "rough draft" java class, which I then copied and pasted the code of into a new java class under the same java project, which seemed to be giving me issues. Once I created a new java project and used the valid java class it worked fine. I also added the pw.flush(); method to my code so I was able to append to the file immediately instead of upon closing. Also removed the system.exit.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
scannerDat.useDelimiter("\r\n");
```

to

```
scannerDat.useDelimiter("\n");
```

Works for me!

Comment: I found this by entering debugging mode and inspecting this line: recUserID = scannerDat.next(); recUserID was "aabbcc-11\nOnetwo3\naaabbb-22\nOnetwo34"

Answer (score 0):

The first bad thing you are doing is that you have a PrintWriter (pw) and a Scanner (scannerDat) both accessing the same file and neither of them closing the access to the file, except right at the end, the pw is closed.

isNewId is the main culprit. Inside here you are better off using a FileReader instead of a Scanner.  Declare the FileReader locally within the method and ensure that the file access is closed before exiting, this procedure.

Also within isNewId - don't call System.exit();  In a program this size it's OK, but anything bigger than this it is a cardinal sin and you should never just exit a program as ungracefully as this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to flush your PrintWriter in order for it to do append to the file immediately. Otherwise it would just store  it in the buffer to write it into the file *eventually*

Also, please check what user @simo.3792095 said about your code. You should not have several file streams opened at the same time. Either open/close your streams every time you do something with them, or read the whole data file on program start, then work with in-memory data, then save on exit. It is much easier to work with in-memory data, but if your program crashes all of the in-memory changes will be lost.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. How do you flush the PrintWriter? And can you explain how I close the streams and where I would do this at. Sorry, like I said, new to java :)